# Runtime error using boost - undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, shared-libraries, boost-system

I am compiling a simple project (shared library) using CMake, this is the content of the CMakeLists.txt

```
set (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

set (LibName test)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(test CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${warnings}")
add_definitions(${GCC_NARROWING})
add_definitions(${GCC_RESOLVEALL})
add_definitions(-DTESTFRAMEWORK_GOOGLE)
add_definitions(-DVARIADIC_MAX=10)
add_definitions(-DENCODING=8)

#include_directories(${GTEST_PATH}/include)
include_directories(${BOOST_PATH})    #${BOOST_PATH} is defined by parent CMakeList
include_directories(${GTEST_PATH}/include ../../ThirdParty/rapidjson_master/include)
set (SOURCES 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Test.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Test.h
    )

message(${LibName})
add_library(${LibName} SHARED ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${LibName} 
  ${OUTDIR}/libboost_system.a 
  ${OUTDIR}/libboost_thread.a
  ${OUTDIR}/libboost_chrono.a
  )
```

I dont receive any error when compiling, when running the program that loads this shared library  I receive:

./test.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv

The program that loads this shared library just do the following:

```
void *m_hTest = dlopen("./test.so", RTLD_NOW);
if (m_hTest == NULL) {
return -1;
}
```

The shared library uses a Thread Local Storage from Boost, inside a class one of the members is:

```
boost::thread_specific_ptr<TLSData> threadData;
```

That is the only thing I am using from boost

Comment: What platform/environment are you using?  Normally, I use `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system)` to find boost.  This usually works fine if you've installed boost using a package manager.  Then I use `target_link_libraries(${LibName} boost::system)` to link and import the appropriate include directories.  There is some great documentation [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html)

Comment: P.S.  The error you've described isn't a "runtime error".  It's a linker error.  Runtime errors occur when you run the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whevener I link to boost with CMake I use [FindBoost.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html).

In your case it would be like this:

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS thread) 
target_link_libraries(${LibName} Boost::thread)
```

Note that linking to `Boost::<target>` is not quite the same as linking to `libboost_<target>.a` because `Boost::<target>` also brings in all dependencies for that target including its include directories and dependent libraries.  In this case, explicitly linking to `Boost::system` and `Boost::chrono` are actually unnecessary because since Boost version 1.50.0, `boost::thread` will actually import system and chrono implicitly.

You don't need to add `include_directories(${BOOST_PATH})` because that is handled by the `find_package` macro and is implicitly linked with the `target_link_libraries` macro.

If you are having troubles finding boost, you can set the `BOOST_ROOT` environment variable to wherever you installed boost.  You can temporarily `set(Boost_DEBUG ON)` if you're still having trouble to troubleshoot where cmake is searching for the libraries and what it is trying to link.

Sometimes I have problems linking with `boost::log` or `boost::chrono` and I find that adding the following often helps:

```
target_link_libraries(${LibName}
                        Boost::disable_autolinking
                        Boost::dynamic_linking
                     )
```

These targets add compile defintions `-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` and `-DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` to your project.